# Comment traduire « heartbeat » dans un contexte informatique ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, informatique

Je cherche à traduire le terme « heartbeat » dans un contexte informatique (voir la [page Wikipédia anglaise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbeat_(computing))). Je n’ai trouvé aucune proposition jusqu’à présent dans mes recherches sur Internet. Quant aux dictionnaires à ma disposition, ils ignorent cet usage du terme.

Comment: [These four, seemingly relevant instances of “battements de **cur**](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?q=battements+de+cur&langFrom=fr&langTo=en&langTot=fr-en&translation=) could just be unintentional misspellings of “cœur,” but if English permits shortening “heartbeat **signal/s**” to just “heartbeat/s,” then shortening “cœur” to “cur” in French to make the distinction would be no less justifiable and much more clever, imo.

Comment: They more likely to be failures to handle the “œ” character than anything else. ;)

Comment: [Minuteur de surveillance](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive) est possible (traduction du KeepAlive), mais la réponse sélectionnée me semble meilleure.

Comment: signal périodique: fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_périodique

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Heartbeat* est couramment utilisé et compris dans ce contexte.

Il existe quelques rares documents, particulièrement [chez IBM](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fr/SSTFXA_6.3.0/com.ibm.itm.doc_6.3/adminuse/eif_autonomy_heartbeatevent.htm), où ce terme est rendu par « **signaux de présence** ».

S'il fallait absolument le traduire par un mot unique, je proposerais « **pulsation** » qui a le mérite d'être court et serait facilement compris ou alors, bien que ce soit trop médical, j'essayerai « **systole** »…

Comment: Certes, mais ça n’en constitue pas une raison pour le conserver ainsi.

En revanche, merci bien pour cette proposition trouvée chez IBM qui me convient parfaitement. :)

Comment: À noter également que dans le même contexte j’ai eu à traduire _to heartbeat_, qui devient aisément « signaler sa présence à » une fois cette traduction retenue. ;)

Comment: Je trouve fort dommage que cette traduction soit retenue, car elle occulte le champs lexical vie/mort. En effet un heartbeat est envoyé tant que l’expéditeur est en vie. Enfin, si c'est la traduction de chez IBM, alors inclinons-nous...

Comment: @Pierre C'est pas faux, mais d'un autre côté, le notion vie/mort est plus souple en informatique où un service peut plus facilement « ressusciter » après un « arrêt cardiaque » prolongé…

Comment: @jlliagre fort heureusement la vivirtuelle n'a pas la même importance, donc comme tu le fais remarquer si justement exactement la même signification. Je notes cependant que tu as pu aisément filer la métaphore, que ça ne choque pas l'oreille, et qu'on comprends parfaitement de quoi tu parles... CQFD

Comment: @Pierre Comment traduiriez-vous alors _to heartbeat_, notamment dans cette phrase : “The interval in seconds for the system to heartbeat the servers.”. C’est la description longue de l’option “Heartbeat interval” dont il était question ici. Je trouve que le choix de « signaux de présence » permet une traduction efficace des deux occurrences, je reste plus sceptique sur toute solution à base de « battements de cœur » ou de « pulsation », mais je ne demande qu’à être convaincu. ;)

Comment: For the verbal form, if pulsation is accepted for the noun (also supported by [Microsoft's official terminology database](http://microsoft.com/language/en-us/Search.aspx?langID=fr‌​-ca) — search "heartbeat" from English to French), then pulser would be the infinitive. Unfortunately, pulser as a transitive verb sounds a little strange because it already means something like "expel", but maybe it works if it's already used in informatique argot...

Comment: @archange, s'il vous plaît faites preuve d'imagination... Je sais pas moi, "donner signe de vie", "présenter un pouls/battement".

Comment: @Luke, sorry it won't, because as you said "pulser" definitly means more "expel", and will unfortunatly be misunderstood (but you're really close in the meaning).

Comment: Pour un signal périodique, [pulsation](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9quence#Pulsation) a un sens totalement différent. Le heartbeat est un signal périodique sous forme d'impulsions dont le retard est interprété comme la défaillance de celui qui doit l'envoyer. C'est le principe de l'[homme mort](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veille_automatique) du ferroviaire. Et donc votre réponse "signal de présence" est tout à fait bonne.

Comment: @mins Tu oublies que le mot dont on cherche la traduction, *heartbeat*, est d'abord un terme médical. Si j'ai proposé « pulsation », c'est donc parce qu'il s'agit de la perception des effets d'un battement de cœur (pulsation cardiaque) qui correspond très exactement au *heartbeat* anglais. Une définition du mot *heartbeat* est d'ailleurs: [*one complete pulsation of the heart*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/heartbeat). Si les pulsations sont irrégulières, c'est qu'il y a un problème, si elles disparaissent, c'est encore plus sérieux...

Comment: Plutôt que pulsation on pourrait carrément utiliiser le mot `pouls`

Comment: @Kii C'est vrai, mais il risque d'être moins facilement compris que *pulsation* qui a l'avantage d'être plus générique et de ne pas être ambigu à l'oral (*le poux*...)

Answer (score 3):

Votre article et la définition suivante parlent essentiellement d'un signal envoyé à intervalles réguliers :

> Signal ou message transmis périodiquement par un dispositif de
>   contrôle à des équipements de réseau, qui est destiné à surveiller
>   leur bon fonctionnement et à s'assurer que certaines opérations
>   s'effectuent normalement.
>
> [ *Grand dictionnaire terminologique* (GDT), [*battement de cœur*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870879) (2002) ]

L'analogie avec le cœur qui bat, le *battement de cœur*, convient parfaitement en français et il n'y a aucune confusion possible avec le rythme cardiaque ; pour une fois que le mot à mot fonctionne. Ailleurs on a aussi identifié une autre suggestion judicieuse, sur l'idée du [*pouls*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/23607). Mais traduire le mot ne suffit pas à en assurer l'emploi dans la langue concrètement et on note la remarque à l'entrée au *GDT* sur les syntagmes *heartbeat message/signal* et on présente donc le choix *message/signal battement de cœur*, sans préposition, pour signaler le type de message ou signal, parfaitement compatible avec l'emploi en langue anglaise, me semble-t-il.

Comment: @jlliagre Ouais, merci !

Comment: Merci pour cette très bonne référence concernant le québécois. Dommage qu’il semble ne pas y avoir d’équivalent pour le français métropolitain.

Comment: @Archange en quoi cette référence concerne le québécois et pas le français métropolitain?

Comment: @Tu ne déroberas. J'aime beaucoup pouls: simple et efficace!

Comment: @Pierre En effet, souvent on croit qu'une référence comme le GDT ou la BDL, du Québec, n'a pas vocation à présenter un français régulier. On se trompe, et d'ailleurs c'est à dessein que j'ai seulement référé à une autre réponse sur l'idée du pouls pour pulsation ; en effet _pulsation_ apparaît dans la même entrée du GDT que celle que je présente. L'entrée est complète, régulière, et a une vocation universelle. Merci.

Comment: Sur la confusion québécois/français métropolitain, c’était dû à une incompréhension de ma part de la réponse suivante : https://french.stackexchange.com/a/23610/12327.

Comment: J’ai précisé les deux occurrences qu’il me faut traduire en commentaire ici : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23603/comment-traduire-heartbeat-dans-un-contexte-informatique/23609?noredirect=1#comment48523_23607

Comment: @Archange Comme on a _message/signal_, le verbe _envoyer_ (_transmettre_ aussi, j'imagine) devient un choix usuel à mon avis dans le contexte de l'intervalle de/du _battement de cœur_ dont vous parlez : ... _pour que le système envoie un (ou son) message/signal battement de cœur aux serveurs_. Notez l'absence de préposition entre message/signal et battement de cœur, tel qu'explicité dans la réponse. Merci.

Comment: @redahabsinpeach Cela me semble beaucoup trop verbeux : « envoie son signal battement de cœur » contre « signale sa présence ». Mais peut-être est-ce juste un problème de concision permise par la langue anglaise qui ne trouve pas son équivalent en langue française.

Comment: @Archange J'aime bien « signale sa présence » comme vous dites, je le trouve tout simplement moins précis/technique, mais en contexte c'est certainement utile. Mais en effet je préfère précision à concision et la longueur n'est généralement pas une considération importante pour moi ds. un texte écrit (mais il y a d'autres contextes que le texte) ; reste qu'on a plusieurs choix. Merci.

Answer (score 3):

***Le*** dictionnaire à connaître pour les termes techniques est [Le grand dictionnaire terminologique](http://www.grand-dictionnaire.com/Resultat.aspx) maintenu par l'Office Québecois de la Langue Française (je n'en connais malheureusement pas d'équivalent français métropoltain).

Il y a une [norme ISO du vocabulaire informatique](http://www.iso.org/iso/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=7229) qui a donc son pendant en Français maintenu par l'AFNOR. Mais l'accès aux documents est payant...

Sinon, le dico sus-cité traduit par *battement de coeur*.

Comment: [_FranceTerme_](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme) j'imagine, sinon faudrait aller au _Journal officiel_...

Comment: La norme ISO dispose d’une nouvelle version en anglais qui est accessible gratuitement, mais même celle-ci ne contient pas le terme _heartbeat_ en fait. Je retiens l’existence du GDT, également proposé par @Ange-à-Liberté, même si c’est effectivement plus orienté québécois que français métropolitain.

Answer (score 2):

Je dirai "battement cardiaque" ou "battement de cœur" tout simplement. Je n'ai rien trouvé non plus à ce sujet, il me semble que le terme est toujours utilisé en anglais.

Cependant il n'est jamais trop tard pour bien faire, pourquoi ne pas utiliser "battement cardiaque" en précisant qu'il s'agit d'une traduction de "heartbeat"?

Plus généralement, de nombreux termes informatiques restent non traduit bien que leur traductions soient triviales... Ceci constitue un anglicisme lexical, ce qui est à mon sens fort dommageable au français et aux français. J'ai souvenir par exemple d'une enseignante d'anglais technique, qui nous demandait la traduction de "to scan". Sa réponse était "numériser"... D'où peux bien provenir une telle inexactitude (vous conviendrez que d'une part, "to scan" peut signifier bien plus que "scanner" un document papier, d'autre part que "numériser" veut dire bien plus que la transformation d'une image analogique en numérique)? Sans doute du fait que trop de spécialistes ont utilisé le terme anglais avant que des non-spécialistes s'occupent de trouver une traduction.

N'ayons pas peur d'être des avant-gardiste, des pionniers de la traduction des termes informatique, à fortiori quand la traduction est triviale.

Comment: Je suis d’accord sur le fond, mais pour mon usage cela me paraît compliqué. Pour être plus précis, je cherche à traduire simplement _Heartbeat Interval_, option apparaissant dans un logiciel. Je ne pense pas qu’« Intervalle des battements de cœur » ou « Intervalle du battement cardiaque » constituent des choix avisés. Les « signaux de présence » proposés me paraissent bien plus appropriés.

Enfin pour reprendre l’exemple de _to scan_,  j’aurais surtout tendance à dire que la traduction dépendra du contexte.

Comment: Effectivement les traductions mot à mot ne donnent rien pour "heartbeat interval", car comme tu le souligne la traduction dépend du contexte. Cependant, il me semble que la traduction reste tout de même triviale. En effet, on emploi généralement en français le terme période pour désigner l'inverse d'une fréquence. "Période cardiaque" semble donc tout trouvé pour "heartbeat interval".

Answer (score 0):

Pourquoi pas « signal rythmique ? »

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language SE.  Voici le [tour] du site et le [help].  Il est utile de donner des citations si possible.

Answer (score 0):

Et pourquoi pas *respiration* ?
Il n'y a pas que le cœur pour témoigner que ça vit toujours :-)

Comment: Il a y une source dans ce contexte ?  Voici le [tour] du site et le [help].